# How to upgrade VBScript application that uses Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0 to C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp-classic, vbscript

I was recently tasked with upgrading a classic ASP web application to C#.  Everything has been fine, except that there is some code that uses `Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")`.  I really don't even know what this is, except I have the general idea that it is being used to call a web service over HTTPS somehow.

The code looks like this:

```
    Dim strSOAPEnvelope

    strSOAPEnvelope = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" & _
                        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" & _
                            "<soap:Body>..........</soap:Body>" & _
                        "</soap:Envelope>"                  

  oXMLHttp.Open "POST", "https://example.com/service.asmx", False
  oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
  oXMLHttp.setOption 2, 13056
  oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
  oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "https://example.com" & strfunction
```

I think that I understand the general notion that this is communicating with a web service via HTTPS.  How do I go about upgrading this code to C#

Comment: You may be interested to know that the language is named "C#", not "C#.NET".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is make a SOAP request to a web service.

The equivalent feature for you is [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), but Web Services in .NET is a full fledged feature. I wouldn't bother creating XML and handling the response.

If you are using .NET 3.0 or higher; you can use Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) to [add a service reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx). The link provides ample instructions on how to do that. Once you've added the service reference, you can call the service's methods using plain C#. All you need to do is point it to the URL which contains the WSDL for the service.

If you are using .NET 2.0, you can use [Web References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx) which should work for SOAP as well.

Comment: I'm familiar with WCF.  If WCF can replace this code, then that sounds like the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

If its only about 1:1 conversion, you could simply use a WebRequest instance to fetch the data and evaluate them manually. This is, what the old code seems to do.

A more elaborate, recommended and easy method would be, to get the webservice description ('wsdl' file), import it and use the proxy classes, which VS created for you automatically out of the wsdl.

VS: Project -> AddWebreference - enter service URL (https://example.com/service.asmx)

If everything goes well, it is as easy as adding a reference to a managed assembly for your project. VS even keeps track of updates to the service.

Overview about the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907578.aspx

And assuming you are using VS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tydxdyw9.aspx

Comment: It's definitely not about a 1:1 conversion.  For this application, we're using MVC 3 and Entity Framework which have no analog in classic ASP.  It's just that when I encountered this particular block of code, I thought it would be easier to ask about it here that to figure it out myself :-)

Comment: The best way is to use a real web service reference than. I'll add some links to my answer.

Comment: -1: Unless there is no choice, he should not use a Web Reference. That uses the legacy ASMX technology which should not be used in new development.

Comment: @John Saunders 1. take a look at the question. The service itself publishes a asmx url. 2. Can you please provide an official reference, that WebReferences are bad practice?

Comment: @PaulWendler: it doesn't matter whether the service is ASMX, that's no reason to use that technology on the client. See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%E2%80%9Clegacy-technology%E2%80%9D/, which shows you where to find pages and pages of official reference. BTW, why would you _want_ to use a web reference when service references are so much more powerful?